# Does the archive command use memory in switch?

Tags: cisco, switch, router, cisco-commands

If I use the `archive` command for automatic backup, does it use memory in switch?

I am planning to set path through TFTP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `archive` command places you in `archive mode`. If you are using this to back up your configuration (`archive config`) you are writing a copy of the configuration to a file in the file system, not RAM memory of the switch.

> [Cisco IOS Configuration Fundamentals Command Reference](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/fundamentals/command/reference/cf_book/cf_a1.html#wp1018716):
>
> **Usage Guidelines**
>
> **Note** Before using this command, you must configure the **path** command in order to specify the location and filename prefix for the
>   files in the Cisco IOS configuration archive.
>
> The Cisco IOS configuration archive is intended to provide a mechanism
>   to store, organize, and manage an archive of Cisco IOS configuration
>   files to enhance the configuration rollback capability provided by the
>   **configure replace** command. Before this feature was introduced, you could save copies of the running configuration using the **copy
>   running-config** *destination-url* command, storing the target file
>   either locally or remotely. However, this method lacked any automated
>   file management. On the other hand, the Configuration Replace and
>   Configuration Rollback feature provides the capability to
>   automatically save copies of the running configuration to the Cisco
>   IOS configuration archive. These archived files serve as checkpoint
>   configuration references and can be used by the **configure replace**
>   command to revert to previous configuration states.
>
> The **archive config** command allows you to save Cisco IOS
>   configurations in the configuration archive using a standard location
>   and filename prefix that is automatically appended with an incremental
>   version number (and optional time stamp) as each consecutive file is
>   saved. This functionality provides a means for consistent
>   identification of saved Cisco IOS configuration files. You can specify
>   how many versions of the running configuration are kept in the
>   archive. After the maximum number of files has been saved in the
>   archive, the oldest file is automatically deleted when the next, most
>   recent file is saved. The **show archive** command displays
>   information for all configuration files saved in the Cisco IOS
>   configuration archive.
>
> **Examples**
>
> The following example shows how to save the current running
>   configuration to the Cisco IOS configuration archive using the
>   **archive config** command. Before using the **archive config** command, you must configure the **path** command to specify the
>   location and filename prefix for the files in the Cisco IOS
>   configuration archive. In this example, the location and filename
>   prefix are specified as disk0:myconfig as follows:
>
> ```
> configure terminal
> !
> archive
>  path disk0:myconfig
>  end
> ```
>
> You then save the current running configuration in the configuration
>   archive, as follows:
>
> ```
> archive config
> ```
>
> The show archive command displays information on the files saved in
>   the configuration archive as shown in the following sample output:
>
> ```
> Router# show archive
>
>
> There are currently 1 archive configurations saved.
> The next archive file will be named disk0:myconfig-2
>  Archive #  Name 
>    0 
>    1       disk0:myconfig-1 <- Most Recent 
>    2 
>    3 
>    4 
>    5 
>    6 
>    7 
>    8 
>    9 
>    10
> ```

Comment: Also note, the archive number resets at boot, so it will overwrite the previous stack of saved versions.